# Extendable models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to structure my models in such a way that there is always a baseUser with the basic functionality that every user needs.

And then in environment a) I might want tot extend this user in another way than in environment b).

My base class:

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class basicUser extends model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'email');

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('remember_token', 'password');

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = array();

    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Rating');
    }


    /*==========  Override class variable declarations for children.  ==========*/

    protected function setFillableAttribute($value)
    {
        if (count(class_parents($this)) > 1) # Check if there is more than one parent, they all need the Eloquent model.
        {
            # Yes, there are parents. We need to combine the parent $fillable with the extra ones in the child.
            $this->fillable = array_unique(array_merge($this->fillable,$value));
        }
        else
        {
            # No parents except Eloquent model.
            $this->fillable = $value;
        }
    }

    protected function setHiddenAttribute($value)
    {
        if (count(class_parents($this)) > 1) # Check if there is more than one parent, they all need the Eloquent model.
        {
            # Yes, there are parents. We need to combine the parent $hidden with the extra ones in the child.
            $this->hidden = array_unique(array_merge($this->hidden,$value));
        }
        else
        {
            # No parents except Eloquent model.
            $this->hidden = $value;
        }
    }

    protected function setGuardedAttribute($value)
    {
        if (count(class_parents($this)) > 1) # Check if there is more than one parent, they all need the Eloquent model.
        {
            # Yes, there are parents. We need to combine the parent $guarded with the extra ones in the child.
            $this->guarded = array_unique(array_merge($this->guarded,$value));
        }
        else
        {
            # No parents except Eloquent model.
            $this->guarded = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea behind the set...Attribute() methods in my base class is that if a child wants to add to $fillable, $hidden or $guarded, the parent value isn't reset.

```
<?php
namespace App\Libraries;

use App\Libraries\basicUser;

class User extends  basicUser
{
    protected $fillable = array('extra');

    protected $hidden = array(); 

    protected $guarded = array();
}
```

Now what I'd really like is for my `$u = user::find(1);` to have password and remember_token to be hidden... but protected $hidden seems to be overridden.

Is this structure even possible? Am I approaching it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**$hidden** is overwritten because you re-declare this attribute in child class. Remove the following from **User** class and it should be enough to make it work:

```
protected $hidden = array();
```

Comment: The point is that I'd like to be able to add to the existing array by just declaring $hidden in the User class.

I could proably do something like:
`protected $hidden_child;

$this->hidden = array_merge($this->hidden,$this->hidden_child);`

But I'd like to do that just by redeclaring (that's why I thought of the set...Attribute() method in the parent class.)

Comment: setHiddenAttribute will be called only if there is no public $hidden atrribute when you try to assign to $object->hidden. It's not called when you declare a variable in "protected $hidden = array();" as PHP's __set() is not called then and thhis is what does all the setXattribute magic

Comment: If you want to expand the $hidden array you need to do that in child class constructor. You'll need to either use array_merge($this->hidden, $someOtherArray) or call setHiddenAttribute explicitely as here the child model has access to $hidden and __set still won't be called

Comment: So basically there is no way to this, except just redeclaring the full from parent + new values?

Comment: It's not possible to do it the way you want, but there are different ways to do that. Extend the array in constructor, overwrite getHidden() method and extend the list there, ...